# redirect to error page when error occurs and access denied in page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, runtime-error

Hi I am doing my project in asp.net now i had a per-designed page for error now how can redirect to error page automatically when error occurred in page loading
and find error code of that page

the errors are like 404 403 400 500 error code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Global.asax` and use the Application_Error method in there handle the exception and redirect. Here is what I am doing :

```
   protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = Context.Error;

        if (ex is HttpUnhandledException)
        {
            ex = Context.Error.InnerException;
        }

        if (ex.GetType().Name == "FileNotFoundException")
        {
            //ignore
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                if ((ex as HttpException).GetHttpCode() == 404)
                {
                    // Page Not found, redirect
                    if (!ex.Message.Contains("error.aspx"))
                    {
                        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
                        Response.AddHeader("Location", "~/error.aspx");
                        Response.End();
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ThrownException)
            {
              //log
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add global.asax page with the following code

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpException ex = (HttpException)Server.GetLastError();
    int httpCode = ex.GetHttpCode();
    if (httpCode == 404)
    {
        //do 404 code work here
    }
    if (httpCode == ???)
    {
        //do ??? code work here
    }
}
```